# Product is empty in shopping cart in list<cart>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, shopping-cart

i use [Shopping in mvc from Microsoft website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n01fU.png)

these are my models and my controllers

```
 public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public int CProductId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerPropertice CProducts { get; set; }
}
```

and this is myproduct(containerPropertice) class. this is product propertice that has relation with product

and this is my addtcart in shoppingCart class

```
 public void AddToCart(ContainerPropertice cProduct)
    {
        // Get the matching cart and album instances
        var cartItem = storeDB.Carts.SingleOrDefault(
            c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId
            && c.CProductId == cProduct.Id);

        if (cartItem == null)
        {
            // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
            cartItem = new Cart
            {
                CProductId = cProduct.Id,
                CartId = ShoppingCartId,
                Count = 1,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now

            };
            storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the item does exist in the cart, 
            // then add one to the quantity
            cartItem.Count++;
        }
        // Save changes
        storeDB.SaveChanges();
    }
```

now when debugger arrive on shopping cart/index to show basket get this error
that cProduct in cart class is empty
in button i put my product class and containerPropertice class

```
 public class ContainerPropertice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Dimension { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Stoke { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    // public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
}
```

and product model class, picture and name get from product class , price get from containerpropertice class

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Summery { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    //public virtual IEnumerable<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ContainerPropertice> ContainerPropertices { get; set; }
```

update1 . i add a picture of cshtml

[image: show error in view]

update 2:this is Index in shoppingcartcontroll

```
 public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        // Set up our ViewModel
        var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
        };
        // Return the view
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

this is actionresult that retirn my view

```
 public virtual ActionResult PDetails(int id)
    {
        var pp = _db.ContainerPropertices.Include(x=>x.Product).Where(x => x.ProductId == id);
        int[] pCount = new int[pp.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < pCount.Length; i++)
        {
            pCount[i] = i + 1;
        }


        ViewBag.ProductCount = new SelectList(pCount);
        ViewBag.ProductCounts = pCount.Length.ToString();
        int stokeIs = pp.Select(x => x.Stoke).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.IsStoke = stokeIs;
        if (stokeIs > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.IsStockStr = "In Stoke";
        }
        if (stokeIs == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.IsStockStr = "Order";
        }

        return View(pp.FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

Comment: i remember someone else asked similar question and change browser can be a different result, can you try?

Comment: no . i change it but the same problem for better describe i update question

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to load CProducts navigation property before rendering the view.
How is your Index() method of Cart controller looking like?